# XAML pages acting different in release mode

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I'm developing a WP7 app with a couple of pages. Everything looks fine in debug mode, but when changing to release mode, two bad things happen:

1. One page remains completely blank (black in dark theme) without throwing any error. However, in the WYSIWYG XAML editor it looks flawless. Also, the code behind is executed (seen using the debugger).
2. On another page, an `ListBox` element is still null after `InitializeComponent()` has finished. It's inside an initially hidden `Popup`.

What are the differences between release and debug build that could cause those issues? I have no idea.

**Update**

The first problem solved itself when I commented everything out and back in, step by step. At the end it worked without any actual changes, so I guess it was a caching problem of Visual Studio or so.

For the second problem, I found a work-around: Setting the container `Popup` to `IsOpen="True"` in XAML and closing it at the very end of the page's constructor (after `InitializeComponent()` has been called). But still I cannot see the reason for it.

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using and what is the target platform?

Comment: What happens when you remove all code from the ctor and NavigatedTo and OnLoaded events of the first page? (the one that is empty)

Comment: @DenDelimarsky: WP SDK 7.1, testing on my Lumia 800 and the emulator (same issues).
(@ShaharPrish: See update)